# Android: Hide the radio button if there is no value from the Database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, radio-button

I'm trying to hide the radio button and it's text if there is no value. The value for the radio button text, I'm getting it from the SQLite Database and I'm setting the visibility of radio button to invisible if one of those fields are empty. However, when I do so, even when there is content in one of the option, it just hides.

Below is my code.

FTR, I didn't hide option1, option2 and pollName because they are never null.

I'm sure I am doing something wrong with the if and else statements but I tried playing around but couldn't find the solution.

**Full Code:**

```
public class ViewPollActivity extends Activity {

    DatabaseHandler DbHandler;
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    TextView txtPollId, txtPollName;
    RadioButton txtOptionName1, txtOptionName2, txtOptionName3, txtOptionName4,
            txtOptionName5;
    Button btndisplay;
    RadioGroup rdgrp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_poll);

        txtPollId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pollId);
        txtPollName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pollName);
        txtOptionName1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        txtOptionName2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        txtOptionName3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        txtOptionName4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        txtOptionName5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio4);
        btndisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.display);
        rdgrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

        // Shared Preferences
        // settings = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
        // String username = settings.getString("username", null);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String pollId = i.getStringExtra("pollId");
        txtPollId.setText(pollId);

        DbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        Cursor c = DbHandler.getSinglePoll(pollId);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String PollName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("pollName"));
            String optionName1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("optionName1"));
            String optionName2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("optionName2"));
            String optionName3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("optionName3"));
            String optionName4 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("optionName4"));
            String optionName5 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("optionName5"));

            txtPollName.setText(PollName);
            txtOptionName1.setText(optionName1);
            txtOptionName2.setText(optionName2);
            txtOptionName3.setText(optionName3);
            txtOptionName4.setText(optionName4);
            txtOptionName5.setText(optionName5);

            if(optionName3 == null) {
                txtOptionName3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
            if (optionName4 == null) {
                txtOptionName4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
            if(optionName5 == null) {
                txtOptionName5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}

        } else {


        }
        c.close();
        DbHandler.close();

        btndisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                String selectedRadioValue = ((RadioButton) findViewById(rdgrp
                        .getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(ViewPollActivity.this, selectedRadioValue,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }// on Create
}// main class
```

Comment: which statement is true if or else when value is null?

Comment: If you want to hide more than one of them, you'll have to use plain if statements, not if-else-if. Else-if will only happen if all of the previous statements in that block are false.

Comment: Also of concern is the fact that all of the OptionNames in your if statements start with capital letters, while the ones above start with lowercase letters. You may be referencing different variables than you think you are.

Comment: I edited my code and that was just typo with the optionNames... I changed it to lowercase o and changed the if statements as above. Despite such changes, I am getting same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use isNull method to check null value.

```
if(OptionName3 ==null ){

  txtOptionName3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. Should I need to set the visibility of these radio buttons in the xml file to invisible as well?

Comment: I got it working, I had to set, if(optionName3 == null || option3.equals("")){
  txtOptionName3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}